# webapp2 2.5.2 in latest 1.7.4 python SDK throws AssertionError: WSGIApplication global variable is not set

Tags: google-app-engine

Just upgraded to latest 1.7.4 GAE python SDK and found that core webapp2 lib was silently (no mentions in [Release Notes](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.7.4_-_December_13,_2012) upgraded to 2.5.2 version. This version contains [backward-incompatible change](http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/detail?r=d962ac4625ce3c43a3e59fd7fc07daf8d7b7c46a).

Under some circumstances it prevents application from starting with error like:

```
File "/usr/local/src/gae/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2_extras/jinja2.py", line 209, in get_jinja2
app = app or webapp2.get_app()
File "/usr/local/src/gae/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1705, in get_app
assert getattr(_local, 'app', None) is not None, _get_app_error
AssertionError: WSGIApplication global variable is not set.
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix from [Fix for webapp2 2.5.2 upgrade in latest 1.7.4 GAE python SDK](http://www.cliws.com/e/XHeDBLl8tNvcn9Ip67PakQ/):

If you faced the same error revert the [above changeset](http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/detail?r=d962ac4625ce3c43a3e59fd7fc07daf8d7b7c46a) or add something like `app.set_globals(app=app)` after your app initialization.

Answer (score 1):

If the library was silently upgraded, it's because you're using "latest" as the version in your app.yaml. If you don't want the version to change, specify the version number. This behaviour is documented at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Configuring_Libraries